# Exponentiation in category of groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

The category of groups $Grp$ and abelian groups $Ab$ don't have exponentiation, I need now:

1. A subcategory of Grp, wich has exponentiation(Is the most biggest subcategory?).
2. A subcategory of Ab, wich has exponentiation(Is the most biggest subcategory?).
3. Exist a category $A$ with exponentiation such that Grp is a subcategory of $A$.
4. Exist a category $B$ with exponentiation such that Ab is a subcategory of $B$.

Comment: You have to explain what do you mean by "exponentiation": is a cartesian closed structure that you want, or a more general monoidal closed one?

Comment: You lack a lot of context. Even assuming you are talking about cartesian products (to make the first sentence correct), you have to realise that answering 2 is also answering 1 (beside the parenthetical question) and answering 3 is also answering 4. Now 3 is always answered positively by taking the presheaves on $Grp$ and $2$ is always answered taking the trivial subcategory... But this is probably not the answer you are looking for. Do you want full subcategories ?

Comment: Exponentiation in this way https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object, respect if 1 implicate 2, no necessary if $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups $ A^B$  is abelian group, unless Ab is subcategory of the response and yes I want a full subcategory.